# Completeness of infinite first-order theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $T$ be a **infinite** first-order theory T, over the empty signature ($\Sigma =$ {}), as follows:
$$T = \{\phi_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
where $$\phi_n \equiv \exists x_{1},\exists x_{2},\exists x_{3},...,\exists x_{n} (x_{1}\not=x_{2} ∧ x_{1}\not=x_{3} ∧ x_{2}\not=x_{3} ∧ ...).$$

Which means: "there exists *at least* $n$ elements in the given domain".

Can you prove this FO theory is **complete**?

Comment: The question needs to be improved. First, it lacks context- where did you encounter the problem? Second, it lacks detail. In particular, without knowing the signature of the theory, we cannot tell whether it is complete. Third, the question does not mention what you have already tried.  You can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: I agree with Carl, particularly as some clues about what has already been done are needed to design an appropriate answer: quantifier-elimination versus categoricity, for example?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. question edited.

Comment: Not voting to reopen, because the question still lacks context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language has no function symbols, predicate symbols, or constant symbols, then the theory is $\omega$-categorical, and therefore complete.

If the language contains a function symbol, or a predicate symbol, or more than one constant symbol, the theory will be incomplete.

Comment: The OP did not specify a signature, without which we do not know if the theory is categorical .

Comment: Since no predicate symbols, function symbols were mentioned, I assume there are none.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the meaning of ω-categorical?  
Can  you specify a signature such that there will be only one structure up to isomorphism the will satisfy T ?

Comment: In general, $\kappa$-categorical means that all models of cardinality $\kappa$ are isomorphic. So $\omega$-categorical means all countably infinite models are isomorphic. The empty signature theory is $\omega$-categorical. The completeness of $T$   is then an immediate consequence of the completeness theorem.  We could also throw in a constant symbol, and the theory would be complete. But we cannot have two constant symbols $a$ and $b$, for then neither $(a=b)$ nor $\lnot(a=b)$ is a theorem of $T$. And as mentioned in the answer, we have incompleteness for all other signatures. (More)

Comment: (More) For example, suppose there is a unary predicate symbol $P$. Then neither $\exists xP(x)$ nor $\lnot\exists xP(x)$ is a theorem of $T$. We can make a complete theory by adding axioms to $T$, but the question was about the completenss of $T$.

Comment: So for example, does the model $\mathbb{R}$ (which is uncountable inifinite) also satisfy $T$? How many different models up to isomorphism satisfy $T$?

Comment: The model you mention does satisfy $T$. There is (up to isomorphism) one model of cardinality $\kappa$ for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$.